# Errors using OpenCV with opencv_contrib on Xcode

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, opencv, opencv-contrib

For my application running on iPhone I am using OpenCV using opencv2.framework in Xcode with objective-c and C++ as languages. My development worked well until I wanted to introduce cv::Tracker that is not included in opencv2.framework but part of opencv_contrib.

1. I rebuilt and installed from the source opencv-3.4.0 with opencv_contrib-master using CMake and terminal commands make and install.
2. In Xcode I have set 
   HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = /usr/local/include and
   LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = /usr/local/lib

When compiling I get a long list of errors of the style:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"cv::error(int, cv::String const&, char const*, char const*, int)", 
referenced from:
cv::Mat::Mat(int, int, int, void*, unsigned long) in OpenCVRenderer.o
"cv::Mat::operator=(cv::Scalar_<double> const&)", referenced from:
cv::Mat::Mat(int, int, int, cv::Scalar_<double> const&) in 
OpenCVRenderer.o
cv::Mat::Mat(cv::Size_<int>, int, cv::Scalar_<double> const&) in 
OpenCVRenderer.o
"cv::Mat::deallocate()", referenced from:
cv::Mat::release() in OpenCVRenderer.o
"cv::polylines(cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, 
bool, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, int, int, int)", referenced from:
.
.
.
```

I set OTHER_LDFLAGS = (list of opencv dylibs) preceeded by a "-" sign

Now I get errors as if the libraries are not found while there are in fact in /usr/local/lib

For example I get:

```
ld: library not found for -libopencv_core.3.4.0.dylib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
```

Any help? 
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: I think it would help if you could say exactly what you put for OTHER_LDFLAGS instead of just describing it.

Comment: @john:OTHER_LFLAGS = -libopencv_core.3.4.0.dylib
-libopencv_highgui.3.4.0.dylib
-libopencv_imgproc.3.4.0.dylib
-libopencv_tracking.3.4.0.dylib 
-libopencv_video.3.4.0.dylib

Comment: @BrianScherady I'm not an expert on the iPhone but if it's anything like other linux environments I would try -lopencv_core.3.4.0 -lopencv_highgui.3.4.0 etc. etc. When linking with a library you normally have -l followed by the library name but you omit the 'lib' prefix and the extension (.dylib, .so or .a) from the library name.

Comment: @john: adding the extension .dylib, at the end of library names, does not help :(

Comment: @BrianScherady Errm, I said remove the dylib extension

Answer (score 0):

There are a couples of problems with your settings.

1. You only specified where to find the libraries, **not** `opencv2.framework`. You should either specify `framework_search_path` (and link your framework to the project) or link the corresponding libraries.
2. You said you were building an iPhone app, yet the error says `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:`. That is, either you built your app for phone simulator or for mac. Yet, your framework is most likely built for iPhone architecture (`armv7` and `arm64`). This case, you need to rebuild the framework. If you build iPhone app, do **not** link any `dylib` libraries in `/usr/local/lib/`.

Note that `libopencv_core.3.4.0.dylib` is part of normal `opencv` so the error has nothing to do with `opencv_contrib` (yet).